# Python - Beautiful Soup 4 - 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have the following code:

```
for route in parsedXml.find_all('route'):
    print(dataCheck(route.find('routesectionref')))
    for routeSection in parsedXml.find(id = dataCheck(route.find('routesectionref'))):
        for routeLink in routeSection.find_all('routelink'):
            print(routeLink)
```

Which returns the error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

The problem being whilst "route" is a "bs4.element.Tag". "routeSection" is a "bs4.element.NavigableString". How can I modify my "routeSection" variable declaration to return a "bs4.element.Tag"?

Comment: Maybe `for routeSection in parsedXml.find_all(...)` will help. But what is `dataCheck`? Can you share URL/XML code and what information are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'` might be happening because what is parsed by BeautifulSoup is actually a string (or contains a string), not an HTML / XML tag.

[Ref](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous): "`AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'foo'` - This usually happens because you’re treating a string as though it were a tag. You may be iterating over a list, expecting that it contains nothing but tags, when it actually contains both tags and strings."